# Get Linkedin OAuth2 access token from token and token secret in Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using linkedin-j. I am using Oauth flow as following to fetch token and token secret. How can I get this oauth2_access_token from token and token secret to call these APIs mannually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn recently launched an official Android SDK which facilitates the authentication work for you, that might simplify this process for you.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Comment: Justin,can you give me an example how to set previous tokens ie, Consumer key & Consumer secret at session initialization time using android-sdk.?

Comment: There is a section in the documentation available at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth that describes how to initialize a session with an existing access token, rather than requesting a new one.  Note, however that it has to be an access token acquired via the Mobile SDK, and not one you previously acquired through REST-based OAuth calls.  Presently, there is no mechanism for exchanging tokens between the two processes.

Comment: when linked app not install in my device how can i get access token and profile data of user